# how to set cache control header on AWS S3 management console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have some problems rendering images on internet explorer and I believe this maybe because there is no cache control header set.

How can I set the cache control header to an individual file on the s3 web management console?

Answer (score 3):

When you have the properties panel of a S3 object loaded, expand the Metadata and add a Cache-Control header (it's even in the dropdown as an option).

Here's my "before":

[image: s3 properties tab]

And "after":

[image: s3 properties tab with cache-control]

There are many great resources for the paremeters of the cache-control header. Two of my favorites are [this tutorial at mnot](https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#CACHE-CONTROL) and [mobify's "beginner's guide to http cache headers"](https://www.mobify.com/blog/beginners-guide-to-http-cache-headers/).