# After updating my AWS S3 bucket with new HTML/JS files, the browser continues to load the old files

Tags: reactjs, caching, amazon-s3

After uploading new files to my S3 bucket, the browser continues to load old files. I run S3 invalidations on all files in Cloudfront which sits in front of my S3 app.

If I have the browser open to my website, I need to refresh several times to see the updated files. I would think that renaming the Javascript file would help, however, the browser is somehow loading the old file probably due to browser cache.

If I clear my browser cache or open in incognito mode, I see the updates immediately. Obviously, I can't tell my users to clear their cache every time I make an update. Is there a solution to this? I often make changes to my API at the same time that the new front-end is dependent on. How can I be sure the newest files are loaded?

Details:
I'm using create-react-app to bundle my S3 app together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the issue. The problem arose due to my app using Service Workers. Create-React-App automatically enables this. If you want the browser to stop caching your React app, make sure to remove the line in index.js that registers service workers.

Comment: In the new CRA, serviceWorker is disabled by default. So if anyone still have this issue, make sure to check your index.html file in s3 and set the `cache-control` value to `max-age=0`

Comment: @ArgaAditya, that is true. CRA now unregisters serviceWorker by default.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `cache-control` header to `max-age 0,no-cache,no-store,must-revalidate` to disable caching

Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33880838/how-to-set-cache-control-header-on-aws-s3-management-console) on how to set file headers

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to this answer this may help you.[refer to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1046966/whats-the-difference-between-cache-control-max-age-0-and-no-cache)

Adding a variable `Cache-Control` to `0` in the header to the selected file in S3

[image]